# Jquery Text change not working on Highlight

Tags: jquery

This is the code that i am using now in my textchange.

```
$(document).on('input propertychange paste', '.ar', function() { 
  alert("change");
});
```

However there is a behavior that my users always do on that textbox. They highlight the text inside then they will press a key to change its value. Its ok for me I think however my code didnt capture that event.

Is there someone who can help me with this?

Comment: First param of the `.on` must be a Jquery known event

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    alert("change");
});
```

---

if it didn't work , try this:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
 alert("change");
});
```

[For more information](https://api.jquery.com/change/)